# Creating a sorted linked list in C

Tags: c, list, hyperlink, sorting

I am looking to create a method to insert a struct in ascending order by the PID's.

I have been checking out other threads and I have written something out like others have mentioned but I get errors when compiling it regarding the `Next_PCB` and type conflicts.

```
struct PCB
{
    struct PCB *Next_PCB;
    int PID;
};

struct PCB *ptr, *tmp;

void insert_ordered (struct PCB *, struct PCB *);
void print_list(struct PCB *);

main()
{
    int num_structs, i;
    ptr = (struct PCB *) malloc (sizeof (struct PCB));
    num_structs = 10 + (rand() % 10);
    for ( i = 0; i < num_structs; i++)
    {
        tmp = (struct PCB *) malloc (sizeof(struct PCB));
        tmp->PID = rand() % 20;
        tmp->Next_PCB = NULL;
        insert_ordered(ptr, tmp);
    }
    print_list(ptr);
}

void insert_ordered (struct PCB *Head, struct PCB *Add)
{
    struct PCB* new;
    if(*Head == NULL || *Head->PID >= Add->PID)
    {
        Add->Next_PCB = *Head;
        *Head = Add;
    }
    else
    {
        new = *Head;
        while (new ->Next_PCB!=NULL && new->Next_PCB->PID < Add -> PID)
        {
            new = new->Next_PCB;
        }
        Add->Next_PCB = new->Next_PCB;
        new->Next_PCB = Add;
    }
}
```

The function `insert_ordered` is where the issue is happening and the way I am working with the structs is what is causing the problem so I'm curious as to what I am doing wrong regarding the method itself as well as the structs.

Comment: It is usually a very bad idea to sort linked lists. The most efficient you can do it is in O(n^2) whereas copying the data to an array, sorting the array and copying back to the list is O(n*log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

You are asking why the compiler would not like the code in insert_ordered().

When I fed your code to GCC, it had 5 problems with the function, and all of them were because you treated `*Head` as a pointer, when it is an instance of `struct PCB`.

`*Head` is not a pointer, to make it a pointer the function prototype should have `struct PCB **Head`. Then `Head` is a pointer to a pointer: it points to the variable owned by the caller, which is in turn the pointer to the head of the list.

So, the code would be:

```
void insert_ordered (struct PCB **Head, struct PCB *Add)
{
  struct PCB* new;
  if ((*Head == NULL) || ((*Head)->PID >= Add->PID))
  {
    Add->Next_PCB = *Head;
    *Head = Add;
  }
  else
  {
    new = *Head;
    while ((new->Next_PCB != NULL) && (new->Next_PCB->PID < Add->PID))
    {
      new = new->Next_PCB;
    }
    Add->Next_PCB = new->Next_PCB;
    new->Next_PCB = Add;
  }
}
```

Of course, the invocation of insert_ordered() must be changed to `insert_ordered(&ptr, tmp) ;`

That works, but as Benjy said, it's not a great algorithm. I assume this is a learning exercise, and that in your next lesson you will be shown a binary tree.

By the way, in `if ((*Head == NULL) || ((*Head)->PID >= Add->PID))` I added some unnecessary brackets. That's because, although the code without the brackets is unambiguous to the compiler, it confuses some of my colleagues. The extra brackets make it more readable... unless you get too many of them. But the brackets in `(*Head)->PID` are needed.

Comment: This will compile, but the assignment to Head: "Head = Add" doesn't do anything but change a local variable that is then ignored.

Comment: @Brad - D'Oh, I shouldn't be let near a computer that late at night. I've edited my answer to avoid confusing anyone looking here later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a couple of problems I may not have found them all, but here is what I see:

- You will need to be able to change the value of the head pointer in the insert routine.  Your insert routine appears to be written to do this since you are already doing operations like "*Head == NULL".  What you need to do know is declare it correctly "struct PCB **Head" and pass it correctly "insert_ordered(&ptr, tmp)".
- You need to handle the initial ptr value correctly. You are mallocing space for it, but not putting anything in it.  Instead you should replace that malloc with an assignment to NULL: "ptr = NULL".